# How can i loop all children of my node and check if any id is used more than once?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, match

I have a function that loops my scene to get a specific node. Once it gets this node, it traverses its children and checks if any of the children have *geometry* or *material* properties. If they do, then I `dispose()` then `remove` the child.

Before I `dispose()` now I want to check if the *geometry.id* of that child matches any other children geometry ids in the scene. If it matches, then I don't `dispose` I just `remove` it. If it doesn't have any matching geometry id, then I can `dispose` then `remove` it.

```
scene.traverse(function(node) {
  if (node.treeNode) { //node has treeNode
    sid.forEach(function(id) {
     if (node.treeNode.sid === id) { 
       if (node.children) {
         node.traverse (function (child) {
          if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
           if (child.geometry) {
           // here check if scene has children of type mesh and any of its
           // children has the same geometryid of this child before disposing it.
            child.geometry.dispose();
           }
           if (child.material) {
             child.material.dispose();
           }
         }
         node.remove(child);
        });
      }
    }
   });
 }
});
```

I would guess it would look something like:

```
  if (node.children) {
        node.traverse (function (child) {
          if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            if (child.geometry) {
               scene.traverse (function(allChildren) {
                  if(allchildren.geometry) { //check if child has geometry first
                     if(allchildren.geometry !== child.geometry.id) {
                        child.geometry.dispose();
                     }
                  }
            }
            if (child.material) {
                child.material.dispose();
            }
          }
          node.remove(child);
         });
    }
```

But I am not sure if I traverse the scene what happens if scene finds the same child I am trying to compare with.

E.g. both `allchildren` and `child` are apart of the scene. If I am comparing them:

```
if (allchildren.geometry !== child.geometry.id)
```

what happens when they are both comparing the same thing. Can this happen? Because `node.geometry` is in scene and `allchildren.geometry` is in scene too.

What I want it to check is if any other `geometry.id` match the one i am currently on.

Please note my geometryId are unique for each mesh. another mesh in the same scene can contain the same geometryId (not unique in this sense)

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: Where does the *traverse* method of *node* come from?

Comment: please see my edited code

Comment: @sarahso `Id` must be **unique** in a page.

Comment: can you provide the structure of the dom and the items you want? your code provides no insights